# Is it appropriate to ask quantitative aptitude math?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is it appropriate to ask quantitative aptitude questions (like the ones in GMAT) in here ?

Comment: I have no idea what you meant by "quantitative aptitude questions" or what you meant by "GMAT". Can you clarify? (With either links or, preferably, an example of what one such question looks like?)

Comment: On Wikipedia [GMAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GMAT) redirects to Graduate Management Admission Test. The Wikipedia article has a short paragraph called quantitative section. I hope that the OP will provide a more detailed clarification of what he meant.

Comment: Since the GMAT quantitative section focuses on elementary mathematics, such as algebra and geometry, why wouldn't such questions be acceptable?