# What is the quantitative-aptitude tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wikis

There are 47 questions tagged [quantitative-aptitude](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantitative-aptitude).  What is this tag, and how should it be used?  The questions seem mostly to be covered by the [arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arithmetic) or [algebra-precalculus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algebra-precalculus) tags.  They look like they could be sample standardized test questions.

It has no wiki summary.  I found [this meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4506/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-quantitative-aptitude-math) asking whether it is okay to ask "quantitative aptitude" questions but not mentioning the tag.

Comment: Googling quantitative aptitude suggests that it is an Indian English term for "problem solving ability" or something similar.

Comment: @DanielR, is there a likely synonym tag that will be more widely recognized?

Comment: @dfeuer If my guess is correct, I think the tag is unnecessary, since it's kind of having a tag called [tag:PSQ]. If the question is about general ways of solving problems, [tag:problem-solving] would be a synonym, but I haven't seen any examples of such questions with the [tag:quantitative-aptitude] tag. It seems that [tag:contest-math] might fit in some cases.

Comment: For the US based people: the term quantitative aptitude is used similarly to how the ETS [uses the term "quantitative reasoning"](http://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/quantitative_reasoning). I personally think that such a tag is unnecessary. Like Nate wrote, most of them can be covered by arithmetic and algebra-precalculus. The few odd ones can fall under problem-solving or contest-math as Daniel commented above.

Comment: Perhaps not everyone knows what the [acronym psq](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3012/common-acronyms-used-on-main-and-meta/) means, so I'll add the explanation: Psq stands for *Problem Statement Question,* a question whose body contains only the statement of a problem.

Comment: I am slowly going through the list to re-tag them all. When I am done I will post an answer indicating such.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, finished.

I've manually retagged those that are better tagged as (elementary-number-theory) or other tags. And the rest I've merged into (algebra-precalculus).

Feel free to re-tag on sight in the future if this tag comes up again.